# Reading items from a csv and updating the same items in another csv

Tags: python, list, csv, ordereddict

I'm working on a method to read data from `input.csv`, and update `stock` column in `output.csv` based on the product's `id`

These are the steps I'm working on right now:

**1.** Read product info from `input.csv` into `input_data = []`, which will return a list of OrderedDict.

`input_data` currently looks like this:

`[OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'a'), ('stock', '33')]), 
OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('name', 'b'), ('stock', '66')]), OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('name', 'c'), ('stock', '99')])]`

**2.** Read current product info from `output.csv` into `output_data = []`, which has the same schema as `input_data`

**3.** Iterate through `input_data` and update the `stock` column in `output_data` based on stock info in `input_data`. **What's the best way to do this?**

-> An important mention is that in `input_data` **there might be some IDs which exist in `input_data` but do not exist in `output_data`**. I would like to **update the stocks** for `id`s common to `input_data` and `output_data`, and the "new" `id`s would most likely be written to a new csv.

I was thinking of something like (this isn't real code):

```
for p in input_data:
    # check if p['id'] exists in the list of output_data IDs (I might have to create a list of IDs in output_data for this as well, in order to check it against input_data IDs
    # if p['id'] exists in output_data, write the Stock to the corresponding product in output_data
    # else, append p to another_csv
```

I know this looks pretty messy, what I'm asking is for a logical way to approach this mission without wasting too much compute time. The files in question are going to be 100,000 rows long, probably, so performance and speed will be an issue.

If my data from `input_data` and `output_data` are a `list` of `OrderedDict` , what is the best way to check the `id` in `input_data` and write the `stock` to the product with the exact same `id` in `output_data`?

Comment: I would recommend checking out pandas for this task: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Python might not be your best option, I wouldn't use lists of OrderDict for this task. This is simply because trying to change something within `output_data` would require O(n) complexity which will simply transform your script in O(n**2).
I would save the two files in dicts (or OrderedDicts if you care about order), like this (and reduce the complexity of the whole thing to O(n)):

```
input_data = {
    '1': ['a', '33'],
    '2': ['b', '66'],
    '3': ['c', '99']
}
output_data = {
    '1': ['a', '31'],
    '3': ['c', '95']
}

# iterate through all keys in input_data and update output_data
# if a key does not exist in output_data, create it in a different dict
new_data = {}
for key in input_data:
    if key not in output_data:
        new_data[key] = input_data[key]
        # for optimisation's sake you could append data into the new file here
        # and not save into a new dict
    else:
        output_data[key][1] = input_data[key][1]
        # for optimisation's sake you could append data into a new output file here
        # and rename/move the new output file into the old output file after the script finishes
```

Comment: Thank you, this has give me a bump in the right direction, that's the sort of data structure I was looking to work with. 
However, I can't seem to read data from the csv in this format, so that each row is `'1' : ['a', '33']`. Any tips on how to achieve this, please?

Comment: I guess you read it line by line and it's something like data = line.split(separator), then input_data[data[0]] = data[1:].

Comment: Thank you! Mulțumesc :)